# How to check if the date is not valid in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to check if the date is not valid in typescript, looking through some of the answers based on javascript. This is the result I came across but unfortunately, it is not working.

```js
...
// Check if the given date is not valid
else if (!(giftCards[i].expiry instanceof Date) || isNaN(Number(giftCards[i].expiry)))
  return new Result(true, ErrorCode.BadRequest, 'Expiry Date out of range', {
    index: i,
    giftCard: giftCards[i]
  });
...
```

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask] and what makes a [mre].  Right now I can't paste your code into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue, since it's a fragment and contains unresolved references (what's `Result`, what's `giftCards`, etc).  It would be helpful for you to provide a true [mre] along with a detailed description of the problem you're running into ("it is not working" is unfortunately not sufficient). Good luck!

Comment: At the moment, your function implies any value that can be converted to a number is a valid date. Is that what you intend? You need to decide precisely what types of value are allowable as dates in your program (only Date objects? Date objects and something else?). Then you can write the function to make the program do that validation.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check if the date is not valid in Typescript

You are trying to check the runtime variable if it's a *valid* `Date` object, which is not the best idea. I would just use javascript to check it.

You could either use e.g. `isDate` function from `lodash` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isdate) or check it manually (and this is what I'm  doing with *dates* in my projects):

```
const isDate = (value: unknown): value is Date => {
   return value instanceof Date && !isNaN(+value);
}
```

**Note**: your code sample *probably* should work fine, but you should replace `||` with `&&` in your condition.